# Can you put a window on a list of virtual desktops, rather than just one or all of them?

Tags: workspaces

I'd like to have certain windows on a list of virtual desktops, not just on one desktop, or all desktops.

For example, if I have these desktops:
1 2 3 4

I'd like to put a window on desktop 1 and 4 at the same time.

Can this be done with Gnome and/or Compiz?

If not, what are the list of options to make this possible?

Answer (score 1):

KDE 4.6 has a great feature called "activities" that allows you to assign applications to virtual workspaces.  This seems like a good blog explaining activities in more detail: http://bsmith1012.blogspot.com/2011/02/changes-in-kde-46-activities.html
As far as I know, it is not possible to do what you want with GNOME.

Answer (score 0):

I do something close to this with Unity in 12.04 by right-clicking on the window's title bar and selecting 'Always on visible workspace'.

Comment: "Always on visible workspace" = "All workspaces". The window will be visible on any workspace the user switches to.

Comment: You're right—I didn't read the question correctly.